# Filter() JQ. Для чего он в этом коде?

Tags: html, jquery, css, css3, html5

Задача здесь - поиск по введённых буквах.
Так вот, всё работает, но я не могу понять для чего мы здесь используем

> filter()

если

> toggle()

делает

> "display: none"

для тех, кто не подошёл по требованиям.
И я часто встречаю

> indexOf(value) > -1

зачем он данном примере? Объясните, пожалуйста, последнюю строку кода, ибо я вроде понимаю, но это не точно )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inputforsearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#tabcontent tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="inputforsearch">
</br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="tabcontent">
    <tr>
      <td>Andrew</td>
      <td>Yaremchuk</td>
      <td>a.yaremchuk99@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vasya</td>
      <td>Vakulenko</td>
      <td>bastaakanoganno@mail.ru</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Miron</td>
      <td>Fedorow</td>
      <td>norimyxxxo@boocking.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `filter` тут действительно ни к чему, более уместен просто `each`. Возможно ранее логика была иной. с тех пор остался filter.

Comment: мы было что то вроде `...filter( ....).toggle(false)` а потом это скомпоновали внутри функции, а filter на each не поменяли

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#inputforsearch").on("keyup", function() {
// как только клавиша отпущена, запускай функцию

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // буква, к нижнему регистру

    $("#tabcontent tr").filter(function() {
    // теперь из всех tr которые потомки #tabcontent отдай выборку-отфильтруй

        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        // функция проходит по каждому элементу tr из набора, смотрит, есть ли данная буква в строке: indexOf(value) указывает позицию буквы, -1 значит отсутствие позиции - буквы нет            
        // а если буквы нет - тоджлим весь tr

    });
});
```

Comment: Вы всё прекрасно расписали, но что фильтрует filter(), если уж сам toggle() уже отбрасывает ненужные нам строки.
А если бы вместо "-1" стояло "0", то мы уже какую-то букву убрали бы, например, "0" - это "А". Извините, что туплю (

Comment: filter в данном случае итерирует по каждому объекту набора. Кстати, можете заменить его на each, например.

Answer (score 0):

Если фильтром пользоваться, то так:

```
$("#tabcontent tr").hide().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
}).show();
```

`indexOf(value) > -1` возвращает расположение введенного текста в другом тексте, -1 если не найден.